# Copying directly from S3 to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I can migrate data from Amazon AWS S3 to Azure using AWS SDK for Java and Azure SDk for Java. Now I want to do migrate data from Amazon AWS S3 to Google Cloud storage using Java.

Answer (score 51):

The [gsutil](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) command-line tool supports S3. After you've [configured gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#authenticate), you'll see this in your ~/.boto file:

```
# To add aws credentials ("s3://" URIs), edit and uncomment the
# following two lines:
#aws_access_key_id = 
#aws_secret_access_key =
```

Fill in the `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` settings with your S3 credentials and uncomment the variables.

Once that's set up, copying from S3 to GCS is as easy as:

```
gsutil cp -R s3://bucketname gs://bucketname
```

If you have a lot of objects, run with the `-m` flag to perform the copy in parallel with multiple threads:

```
gsutil -m cp -R s3://bucketname gs://bucketname
```

Comment: how to use profile based operations in gstuil while copying files from local to S3?

Comment: Isn't the `rsync` command a better fit for this use case? If it is truly a one-off migration it will be the same, but if it needs to happen multiple times or on an ongoing basis, `rysnc` will save a lot of transferring. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/interoperability

Comment: Note that I believe the "configure command" referred to in this answer (which creates the `.boto` file) is `gcloud init`. I'm not too confident in my knowledge so I won't edit the answer, but I wanted to put it out there.

Comment: @Stephen sorry, a lot's changed since 2014 when I original wrote the answer. I edited the answer to make it more clear now.

Answer (score 18):

Use the Google Cloud Storage [transfer tool](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/create-manage-transfer-console).

[image: Google Cloud Storage Transfer Tool]

Comment: unfortunately there is no ```gsutil transfer``` to do this from the commandline. The transfer tool is nice but web-only so no scripting possible. Or does somebody know how to address the transfer tool programatically?

Comment: scripting is possible: https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-program

Answer (score 5):

The answer suggested by jterrace (aws key and secret in .boto file) is correct and worked for me for many regions but not for some regions that need only AWS Signature Version 4. For instance while connecting to 'Mumbai' region I got this error:

BadRequestException: 400 InvalidRequest
**The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256**

In order to overcome this problem (make gsutil use AWS Signature v4) I had to add following additional lines to ~/.boto file. These lines create a new section [s3] in the config file:

**[s3]

host = s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com

use-sigv4 = True**

Reference:
[Interoperability support for AWS Signature Version 4](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62161892) 
[Gsutil cannot copy to s3 due to authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929964/gsutil-cannot-copy-to-s3-due-to-authentication?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Create a new .boto file

```
[Credentials]
aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY_ID
aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

and this command

```sh
BOTO_CONFIG=.boto gsutil -m cp s3://bucket-name/filename gs://bucket-name
```

or this

```sh
BOTO_CONFIG=.boto gsutil -m cp gs://bucket-name/filename s3://bucket-name
```