# gsutil cannot copy to s3 due to authentication

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I need to copy many (1000+) files to s3 from GCS to leverage an AWS lambda function. I have edited `~/.boto.cfg` and commented out the 2 aws authentication parameters but a simple `gsutil ls s3://mybucket` fails from either an **GCE** or **EC2** VM.

Error is `The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.`.

I use gsutil version: `4.28` and locations of **GCS** and **S3** bucket are respectively `US-CENTRAL1` and `US East (Ohio)` - in case this is relevant.

I am clueless as the AWS key is valid and I enabled http/https. Downloading from GCS and uploading to S3 using my laptop's Cyberduck is impracticable (>230Gb)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As per https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62161892, `gsutil` v4.28 **does** support `AWS` v4 signatures by adding to `~/.boto` a new `[s3]` section like

```
[s3]
# Note that we specify region as part of the host, as mentioned in the AWS docs:
# http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region
host = s3.eu-east-2.amazonaws.com
use-sigv4 = True
```

The use of that section is inherited from `boto3` but is currently not created by `gsutil config` so it needs to be added explicitly for the target endpoint.

For s3-to-GCS, I will consider the more server-less `Storage Transfer Service` API.

Comment: gsutil does support this as of version 4.28 -- the issue you linked just didn't get updated until now, apologies :) Please consider changing your answer to reflect this.

Comment: @mhouglum thanks for the tip ! Answer and issuetracker updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Here is what I ended up doing on a GCE machine:

Step 1: Using gsutil, I copied files from GCS to my GCE hard drive
Step 2: Using aws cli (aws s3 cp ...), I copied files from GCE hard drive to s3 bucket

The above methodology has worked reliably for me. I tried using gsutil rsync but it fail unexpectedly.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks - ended up doing that for a one-time transfer but I need to do the same the other way round to load into BigQuery + eventually this will happen daily. Copying locally is a workaround but still believe there is an issue with `gsutil`